# Referencing path-dependent type of an argument in the type of another argument to a constructor

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

I have automata, which have dependent types (I would call them associated) for the states and labels of their transitions.

```scala
trait Automaton {
  type State
  type Label
  type Transition = (State, Label, State)
}
```

Now I want to write a class that takes as its argument an automaton and a function doing some sort of counting for transitions on that particular automaton. I would write:

```
class AutomataMagic(val aut: Automaton, val h: aut.Transition => Int) {

...
}
```

However, [that doesn't compile](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bk8yhDhvQcqkkpYH5V7RDw). Is there any way I can specify that I want my function to do things to specifically *this* automaton's transition type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all:

```
illegal dependent method type: parameter may only be referenced in a subsequent parameter section
```

As Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252557/referencing-path-dependent-type-of-an-argument-in-the-type-of-another-argument-t/65252719?noredirect=1#comment115360224_65252719), you need to move `h` to another parameter group.

```scala
class AutomataMagic(val aut: Automaton)(val h: aut.Transition => Int) {}
```

Oddly enough, that [doesn't work](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GFkPoYa0TMOj0JPcPVdAzQ) (probably because of [this bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5712)).

A (very naive) workaround would be [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/azSiWngyRriIgV4rOtq7SA). It's not very satisfying, but it seems to work.

```scala
class AutomataMagic private(_h: Automaton#Transition => Int, val aut: Automaton) {
  val h: aut.Transition => Int = _h.asInstanceOf[aut.Transition => Int]
  def this(aut: Automaton)(h: aut.Transition => Int) =
    this(h.asInstanceOf[Automaton#Transition => Int], aut)
}
```

EDIT: Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez suggested using a trait with a companion object. [Here's](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gfQJgZe2Qi6vJqIsVpSgzQ) my interpretation of that:

```scala
trait AutomataMagic[A <: Automaton] {
  val aut: A
  val h: aut.Transition => Int
}
object AutomataMagic {
  def apply[A <: Automaton](_aut: A)(_h: _aut.Transition => Int) = new AutomataMagic[A] {
    val aut: _aut.type = _aut
    val h = _h
  }
}
```

By the way, the first snippet [compiles in Scala 3](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/17NyshA6QKiGYcQxN50T7g).

---

Also, you really shouldn't use this:

```
class AutomataMagic[A <: Automaton](val aut: Automaton, val h: A#Transition => Int) {}
```

Not only is `A#Transition` unrelated to `aut.Transition` (at least make it `aut: A`), type projections [are unsound](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/1050) and will be dropped in Scala 3. Maybe it won't matter to you in this specific case because `Transition` is invariant, but it is not safe.

Comment: To get this to work I will probably need to do some other refactoring, but that's for the best and will probably improve my code quality. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. Apparently, you can just do this:

```scala
class AutomataMagic[A <: Automaton](val aut: Automaton, val h: A#Transition => Int) {}
```

Comment: Don't do that, that doesn't mean what you think it does and type projections are being deprecated. The first one will compile if you move the function to another parameter group.